# Change value on column based on another column mssql

Tags: sql-server

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I would like to achieve the following

```
EI  AC 
P3  1
UT  1
P4  0
P1  1
P2  0
```

A sort of case statement like: `case when AC = 0 then EI = EX`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows

```
select
    'EI' = case
             when a.AC = 0
                then 'EX'
             else a.EI
           end,
    a.AC
from
    your_Table as a
```

Comment: @Henkiee20 Do your part to help future visitors and to show appreciation to the people that volunteer to help. If this response solves your issue, then please mark it as the answer.